# Chaining context through akka streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm converting some C# code to scala and akka streams.

My c# code looks something like this:

```cs
Task<Result1> GetPartialResult1Async(Request request) ...
Task<Result2> GetPartialResult2Async(Request request) ...

async Task<Result> GetResultAsync(Request request) 
{
    var result1 = await GetPartialResult1Async(request);
    var result2 = await GetPartialResult2Async(request);
    return new Result(request, result1, result2);
}
```

Now for the akka streams. Instead of having a function from `Request` to a `Task` of a result, I have flows from a Request to a Result.

So I already have the following two flows:

```scala
val partialResult1Flow: Flow[Request, Result1, NotUsed] = ...
val partialResult2Flow: Flow[Request, Result2, NotUsed] = ...
```

However I can't see how to combine them into a complete flow, since by calling via on the first flow we lose the original request, and by calling via on the second flow we lose the result of the first flow.

So I've created a WithState monad which looks something like this:

```scala
case class WithState[+TState, +TValue](value: TValue, state: TState) {
  def map[TResult](func: TValue => TResult): WithState[TState, TResult] = {
    WithState(func(value), state)
  }
  ... bunch more helper functions go here
}
```

Then I'm rewriting my original flows to look like this:

```scala
def partialResult1Flow[TState]: Flow[WithState[TState, Request], WithState[TState, Result1]] = ...
def partialResult2Flow: Flow[WithState[TState, Request], WithState[TState, Result2]] = ...
```

and using them like this:

```scala
val flow = Flow[Request]
    .map(x => WithState(x, x))
    .via(partialResult1Flow)
    .map(x => WithState(x.state, (x.state, x.value))
    .via(partialResult2Flow)
    .map(x => Result(x.state._1, x.state._2, x.value))
```

Now this works, but of course I can't guarantee how flow will be used. So I really ought to make it take a State parameter:

```scala
def flow[TState] = Flow[WithState[TState, Request]]
    .map(x => WithState(x.value, (x.state, x.value)))
    .via(partialResult1Flow)
    .map(x => WithState(x.state._2, (x.state, x.value))
    .via(partialResult2Flow)
    .map(x => WithState(Result(x.state._1._2, x.state._2, x.value), x.state._1._1))
```

Now at this stage my code is getting extremely hard to read. I could clean it up by naming the functions, and using case classes instead of tuples etc. but fundamentally there's a lot of incidental complexity here, which is hard to avoid.

Am I missing something? Is this not a good use case for Akka streams? Is there some inbuilt way of doing this?

Comment: Why you can not use Future instead of Flow? It's more simple, and easy to combine. Future is *standard* class in Scala, than almost each Scala developer know how to use it.

Comment: My team has decided we want to use Akka streams for it's benefits in creating back pressure, and I'm evaluating it for our use case. It could well be that is not the right solution, in which case we won't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any fundamentally different way to do this than I described in the question.

However the current flow can be significantly improved:

### Stage 1: FlowWithContext

Instead of using a custom `WithState` monad, it's possible to use the built in `FlowWithContext`.

The advantage of this is that you can use the standard operators on the flow, without needing to worry about transforming the `WithState` monad. Akka takes care of this for you.

So instead of

```scala
def partialResult1Flow[TState]: Flow[WithState[TState, Request], WithState[TState, Result1]] = 
    Flow[WithState[TState, Request]].mapAsync(_ mapAsync {doRequest(_)})
```

We can write:

```scala
def partialResult1Flow[TState]: FlowWithContext[Request, TState, Result1, TState, NotUsed] = 
    FlowWithContext[Request, TState].mapAsync(doRequest(_))
```

Unfortunately though, whilst FlowWithContext is quite easy to write when you don't need to change the context, it's a little fiddly to use when you need to go via a stream which requires you to move some of your current data into the context (as ours does). In order to do that you need to convert to a `Flow` (using `asFlow`), and then back to a `FlowWithContext` using `asFlowWithContext`.

I found it easiest to just write the whole thing as a `Flow` in such cases, and convert to a `FlowWithContext` at the end.

For example:

```scala
def flow[TState]: FlowWithContext[Request, TState, Result, TState, NotUsed] = 
  Flow[(Request, TState)]
    .map(x => (x._1, (x._1, x._2)))
    .via(partialResult1Flow)
    .map(x => (x._2._1, (x._2._1, x._1, x._2._2))
    .via(partialResult2Flow)
    .map(x => (Result(x._2._1, x._2._2, x._1), x._2._2))
    .asFlowWithContext((a: Request, b: TState) => (a,b))(_._2)
    .map(_._1)
```

Is this any better?

In this particular case it's probably worse. In other cases, where you rarely need to change the context it would be better. However either way I would recommend using it as it's built in, rather than relying on a custom monad.

### Stage 2: viaUsing

In order to make this a bit more user friendly I created a `viaUsing` extension method for Flow and FlowWithContext:

```scala
import akka.stream.{FlowShape, Graph}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, FlowWithContext}

object FlowExtensions {
  implicit class FlowViaUsingOps[In, Out, Mat](val f: Flow[In, Out, Mat]) extends AnyVal {
    def viaUsing[Out2, Using, Mat2](func: Out => Using)(flow: Graph[FlowShape[(Using, Out), (Out2, Out)], Mat2]) : Flow[In, (Out2, Out), Mat] =
      f.map(x => (func(x), x)).via(flow)
  }

  implicit class FlowWithContextViaUsingOps[In, CtxIn, Out, CtxOut, Mat](val f: FlowWithContext[In, CtxIn, Out, CtxOut, Mat]) extends AnyVal {
    def viaUsing[Out2, Using, Mat2](func: Out => Using)(flow: Graph[FlowShape[(Using, (Out, CtxOut)), (Out2, (Out, CtxOut))], Mat2]):
    FlowWithContext[In, CtxIn, (Out2, Out), CtxOut, Mat] =
      f
        .asFlow
        .map(x => (func(x._1), (x._1, x._2)))
        .via(flow)
        .asFlowWithContext((a: In, b: CtxIn) => (a,b))(_._2._2)
        .map(x => (x._1, x._2._1))
  }
}
```

The purpose of `viaUsing`, is to create the input for a `FlowWithContext` from the current output, whilst preserving your current output by passing it through the context. It result in a `Flow` whose output is the a tuple of the output from the nested flow, and the original flow.

With `viaUsing` our example simplifies to:

```scala
  def flow[TState]: FlowWithContext[Request, TState, Result, TState, NotUsed] =
    FlowWithContext[Request, TState]
      .viaUsing(x => x)(partialResult1Flow)
      .viaUsing(x => x._2)(partialResult2Flow)
      .map(x => Result(x._2._2, x._2._1, x._1))
```

I think this is a significant improvement. I've made a request to add viaUsing to Akka instead of relying on extension methods [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/28431).

Answer (score 1):

I agree using Akka Streams for backpressure is useful. However, I'm not convinced that modelling the calculation of the `partialResult`s as streams is useful here. having the 'inner' logic based on `Future`s and wrapping those in the `mapAsync` of your flow to apply backpressure to the whole operation as one unit seems simpler, and perhaps even better.

This is basically a boiled-down refactoring of Levi Ramsey's earlier excellent answer:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future }
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

case class Request()
case class Result1()
case class Result2()
case class Response(r: Request, r1: Result1, r2: Result2)

def partialResult1(req: Request): Future[Result1] = ???
def partialResult2(req: Request): Future[Result2] = ???

val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem()
implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = system.dispatcher

val flow: Flow[Request, Response, NotUsed] =
  Flow[Request]
    .mapAsync(parallelism = 12) { req =>
      for {
        res1 <- partialResult1(req)
        res2 <- partialResult2(req)
      } yield (Response(req, res1, res2))
    }
```

I would start with this, and only if you know you have reason to split `partialResult1` and `partialResult2` into separate stages introduce an intermediate step in the `Flow`. Depending on your requirements `mapAsyncUnordered` might be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I'm not totally familiar with C#'s async/await.

From what I've been able to glean from a quick perusal of the C# docs, `Task<T>` is a strictly (i.e. eager, not lazy) evaluated computation which will if successful eventually contain a `T`.  The Scala equivalent of this is `Future[T]`, where the equivalent of the C# code would be:

```
import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future }

def getPartialResult1Async(req: Request): Future[Result1] = ???
def getPartialResult2Async(req: Request): Future[Result2] = ???

def getResultAsync(req: Request)(implicit ectx: ExecutionContext): Future[Result] = {
  val result1 = getPartialResult1Async(req)
  val result2 = getPartialResult2Async(req)
  result1.zipWith(result2) { tup => val (r1, r2) = tup
    new Result(req, r1, r2)
  }
  /* Could also:
   *   for {
   *     r1 <- result1
   *     r2 <- result2
   *    } yield { new Result(req, r1, r2) }
   *
   * Note that both the `result1.zipWith(result2)` and the above `for`
   * construction may compute the two partial results simultaneously.  If you
   * want to ensure that the second partial result is computed after the first 
   * partial result is successfully computed:
   *   for {
   *     r1 <- getPartialResult1Async(req)
   *     r2 <- getPartialResult2Async(req)
   *   } yield new Result(req, r1, r2)
   */
}
```

No Akka Streams required for this particular case, but if you have some other need to use Akka Streams, You could express this as

```
val actorSystem = ??? // In Akka Streams 2.6, you'd probably have this as an implicit val
val parallelism = ??? // Controls requests in flight

val flow = Flow[Request]
  .mapAsync(parallelism) { req =>
    import actorSystem.dispatcher

    getPartialResult1Async(req).map { r1 => (req, r1) }
  }
  .mapAsync(parallelism) { tup =>
    import actorSystem.dispatcher

    getPartialResult2Async(tup._2).map { r2 =>
      new Result(tup._1, tup._2, r2)
    }
  }

  /* Given the `getResultAsync` function in the previous snippet, you could also:
   *   val flow = Flow[Request].mapAsync(parallelism) { req =>
   *     getResultAsync(req)(actorSystem.dispatcher)
   *   }
   */
```

One advantage of the `Future`-based implementation is that it's pretty easy to integrate with whatever Scala abstraction of concurrency/parallelism you want to use in a given context (e.g. cats, akka stream, akka).  My general instinct to an Akka Streams integration would be in the direction of the three-liner in my comment in the second code block.

Comment: Thanks. I'm more interested in how to pass context throught flows at the moment though - I've worked out how we could do a literal translation to Scala, but we've decided to use Akka streams as far as possible in our solution.

Comment: Tupling or the moral equivalent thereof is probably the only reasonable way to do that with Akka Streams: the standard operators are strongly oriented toward input-to-output and discarding the input afterwards.  You can get around this with a custom `GraphStage` to thread context through to the end, but I'm generally wary of a custom `GraphStage` that has a single input and single output.